# How to add new line using sed on MacOS?

Tags: sed

I wanted to add a new line between `</a> and <a><a>`

```
</a><a><a>

</a>
<a><a>
```

I did this

`sed 's#</a><a><a>#</a>\n<a><a>#g' filename` but it didn't work.

Comment: Isn't it `sed 's#</a><a><a>#</a>\n<a><a>#g' filename`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried with 's' but still didn't work

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Wrong output? Error message? Something else?

Comment: Replace \n with \x0D, credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909903/1682506

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some `sed`s, notably Mac / BSD, don't interpret `\n` as a newline, you need to use an actual newline, preceded by a backslash:

```sh
$ echo foo | sed 's/f/f\n/'
fnoo
$ echo foo | sed 's/f/f\
> /'
f
oo
$
```

Or you can use:

```sh
echo foo | sed $'s/f/f\\\n/'
```

Comment: And if you need to change '\n' --> NEWLINE you should use 2 steps:

cat file | sed 's/\\n/±/g' | sed $'s/±/\\\n/g'. Note '±' is random character, not used in stream.

Comment: echo foo | sed $'s/f/f\\\n/' worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

Powered by mac in two Interpretation:

1. `echo foo | sed 's/f/f\'$'\n/'`
2. `echo foo | gsed 's/f/f\n/g'`

Comment: How can I install gsed on a mac?

Comment: The solution #1 should be marked as the most correct answer to this question.

Comment: ELI5?   Please? I don't understand why we're escaping the single quote before the dollar sign.

Comment: @becko You can install `gsed` using Homebrew: `brew install gsed`.

Comment: The way (1) works, it concatenates 2 strings, the first one is literally "s/f/f\", the dollar sign before second string expands "\n" to the actual new-line character. That way, `sed` receives following string: `s/f/f\↵/`.

Comment: I got gsed with `brew install gnu-sed`.

Comment: The problem with this one is that Xcode doesn't know how to correctly highlight the syntax.

Comment: how to do this when the sed string must be quoted to include a bash variable?

Answer (score 0):

...or you just pound on it! worked for me on insert on mac / osx:

```
  sed "2 i \\\n${TEXT}\n\n" -i ${FILE_PATH_NAME}
  sed "2 i \\\nSomeText\n\n" -i textfile.txt
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the mac osx version? I have this output `sed: 1: "2 i \\nSomeText\n\n": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`

Answer (score 0):

on macOS 13.5 Ventura, 2023, this works:

```
sed -i '' '2i\'$'\n''line 2'$'\n' x
```

Which insert a line 2 into the existing file x, this new line containing “line 2”

1. $'\n' is how a newline is typed on macOS
2. two single-quoted strings next to each other are merged into one by bash/zsh
3. the back-slash newline sequence is required by sed command i

Best operating system in the world according to Apple