# Problem with combining lines form file with custom text in cout

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I have problem with combining strings from getline with other ones in cout, i have been searching answers but I couldn't find anyone who had similiar problems. My code is:

```
file.open ("list.txt");
    getline(file, line);
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        getline(file, line);
        dummyStudent.name = line;
        cout << "Is " << flush << dummyStudent.name << flush << " present?" << endl;
        students.push_back(dummyStudent);
        i++;
    }
    while(!file.eof());
    file.close();
```

The output should be:

```
Is student present?
```

But instead i get:

```
 present?udent
```

and the last iteration of loop shows correct text.

Comment: I believe this is your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints

Comment: @Kai doesn't look like it. Everything in that `cout` statement is independent of each other, so there's shouldn't be UB because of sequence points here.

Comment: Maybe its due to carriage return (`\r`) at the end of each line except the last?

Comment: Can you check the result of `getline` to see if it's `false`?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

Let me take a guess here. Your file was created or edited on Windows, but you're not using Windows to build/run your code. So instead of newline characters at the end of each line (`\n`) you have newlines *and* carriage returns: `\r\n`. However there's no newline (and so no carriage return) on the very last line of the file--so only that one looks good. Am I right?

A carriage return will return the cursor to the beginning of the line. So you read in `student\r` and then `std::cout` writes `Is student`, sees the carriage return and moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line and writes `present?` there. Resulting in `present?udent`.

Either strip the whitespace from the end of your `name` string (with the help of code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/217605/2602718)

```
static inline void rtrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](int ch) {
        return !std::isspace(ch);
    }).base(), s.end());
}

int main() {
    //...
    getline(file, line);
    dummyStudent.name = line;
    rtrim(dummyStudent.name);
    cout << "Is " << flush << dummyStudent.name << flush << " present?" << endl;
    //...
```

Or remove those characters from your file. (After hearing that you're on MacOS, you could remove those characters from the file with something like this: [Removing Carriage return on Mac OS X using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21621722/2602718))

Comment: shouldn't be a problem on windows with the file opened in text mode. should only be a problem in binary mode or reading windows files on other platforms

Comment: I guess I just assumed they were on Linux @Alan. I've edited to make explicit the assumption that they're not building/running on Windows. Good catch!

Comment: The question is tagged visual-c++ so I assume they are on windows. Stray carriage returns is definitely the issue though

Comment: my file was eddited on windows but I'm on a mac

Comment: @Bruno in that case I'd look at running something like this on your file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21621722/2602718

Comment: I'll try thank you